# Redirect user to a page with HTTP Basic Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, redirect

In C#.net I want to redirect a user to a web page which the web page requires HTTP basic authentication.

How can I do that in C# or any example for me to reference?

1) I don't want to use pass userid and password in url as query string

2) I knew that I can pass request header like `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpv2FtZQ==` but how can I redirect to page after pass request header??

Thank a lots!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Response.Redirect("name of your page");
```

OR:

```
Server.Transfer("name of your page");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems just redirect to other page, I need to redirect page **with basic authentication**  Thanks!